# how to generate apns certificate in openshift server

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications, openshift

I am trying to use push notifications through my nodejs server deployed in openshift rehat server. I could not find any documentation/discussion to generate apns certificate in openshift.

I tried generating a certificate, but getting an error while generating CSR using this command

```
openssl genrsa -out sz.key 2048
```

Error: `unable to write 'random state'
e is 65537 (0x10001)`

After some googling, I see one option is to use [aerogear](http://aerogear.org/). But I want to use my own server to handle the notifications.

Is there any other option to generate a certificate in openshift server?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks *developercorey* for your help. But i still see the error.

Finally generated certificate for my openshift server using this script

```
openssl x509 -in aps_production.cer -inform DER -out myProdCert.pem
```

The private key associated with the SSL certificate can be exported from the Keychain Access application on your Mac computer.  - mykey.p12

```
openssl pkcs12 -in mykey.p12 -out myProdKey.pem -nodes -clcerts
openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert myProdCert.pem -key myProdKey.pem
```

Hopefully this will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
HOME=~/app-root/data/  openssl genrsa -out sz.key 2048
```

Basically it is trying to write some temp data into your $HOME, but you can't write to that directory, so it won't work, but it does give somewhat of a cryptic error message.